# Divs expandable upward on click

Tags: html, click, expand

I have these two expandable divs: https://jsfiddle.net/ar0j4508/31/

```
<div class="container_one">
    <div class='header'></div>
    <div class='container_two'>
        <div class='title show'>From 4 to 0</div>
        <div class="text hide"><br>4<br>3<br>2<br>1<br>0<br></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to know:
1) - How to automatically show all the contained text on click;
2) - How to expand one div without expanding the other. Thanks.

Comment: I might consider a different structure. What should happen if a `.text` box is too tall to fit inside `.container_one`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first one How to automatically show all the contained text on click - You can do it by increasing the height of `container_two div` by the height of `text div`

For the second one How to expand one div without expanding the other - You can do it by performing your script part for the particular `divs` in which the `click` event was triggered by using `$(this) keyword like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".show").click(function() {
    var $par = $(this).parent(".container_two");
    if ($par.attr('vis') == 'show') return;
    $par.parent(".container_one").find(".header").animate({
      height: '-=' + $par.find(".text").height()
    })
    $par.animate({
      height: '+=' + $par.find(".text").height()
    });

    $par.attr('vis', 'show');
  })

  $(".hide").click(function() {
    var $par = $(this).parent(".container_two");
    if ($par.attr('vis') == 'hide') return;
    $par.animate({
      height: '-=' + $par.find(".text").height()
    });
    $par.parent(".container_one").find(".header").animate({
      height: '+=' + $par.find(".text").height()
    })
    $par.attr('vis', 'hide');
  })
})
```

```css
.header {
  width: 250px;
  height: 400px;
  max-height: 400px;
}

.container_one {
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
}

.container_two {
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.title {
  background: #0f0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.text {
  background: #0f0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container_one">
  <div class='header'></div>
  <div class='container_two'>
    <div class='title show'>From 4 to 0</div>
    <div class="text hide"><br>4<br><br>4<br>3<br>2<br>1<br>0<br></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container_one">
  <div class='header'></div>
  <div class='container_two'>
    <div class='title show'>From 8 to 0</div>
    <div class="text hide"><br>8<br>7<br>6<br>5<br><br>4<br>3<br>2<br>1<br>0<br></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why I added `max-height:400px;` to header class- This is because when you are hiding the content then you are increasing the height of div by height of text and if height of text is more than 400px then on hiding the height of header will increase which will result in non-allignment of two divs(It will happen in the case when you show the second div and then hide that div.Try without  `max-height`)

Comment: Exceptional. Now i'm stuck on this: in this example (https://jsfiddle.net/s6Lob6zo/3/), how can i push back the divs clicking on the dark green section too? Very thanks.

Comment: you mean pushing back the div by clicking on `show` class div also??

Comment: @LuigiP. I have updated your fiddle now you can even close the div clicking on dark green section two. I have also fixed the height issue of the text div. Previously one number was visible along with the title. Now that issue is also fixed.  Here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/s6Lob6zo/5/

Comment: Really kind and qualified, thanks a lot. One only thing, on firefox the last number appears halved. On IE is perfect.

Comment: Updated - It seems Firefox uses a different line-height than IE, this is why the text appears different. Changing the default line-height of the browser should do the trick.